# Is it possible to invoke functions used to create parameters for a method from inside that method? (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, delegates

This is a bit hard to explain, but I'm hoping this example will clear it up.

Say I have some function call Visible:

```
public bool Visible(/* Some page element */)
    {
        // Checks if something on a webpage is visible. Returns a "true" is yes, and "false" if not
    }
```

Is it possible to some how wait for this function to return true? What I've written out so far looks like this:

```
    public void WaitUntil(/*function returning bool*/ isTrue)
    {
        for (int second = 0; ; second++)
        {
            if (second >= 12)
            {
                /* Thow exception */
            }
            else
            {
                if (isTrue /*calls the isTrue function with given parameters*/)
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Such that these two method could be used together like:

```
WaitUntil(Visible(/* Some page element */));
```

to wait until a page element is visible... Is this possible?

Comment: I think you should maybe use an event, or simply implement the call to  whatever you do in waituntil into the method making something visible or not on the page.

Comment: What are you working on? - WebForms contains EventHandler for PageLoaded - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397523(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: how are you going to test if something has become visible on the page with server side code?

Comment: If this is server-side code, something like this will block the page load. The user will see a long delay with no explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to do it (although you should consider using events as this kind of "waiting" is strongly discouraged)

```
/*Important Note: This is ugly, error prone 
          and causes eye itchiness to veteran programmers*/
public void WaitUntil(Func<bool> func)
{
    DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
    while(DateTime.Now - start < TimeSpan.FromSeconds(12))
    {
        if (func())
        {
                return;
        }
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
    /* Thow exception */
}

//Call
WaitUntil(() => Visible(/* Some page element*/));
```